# How to run a custom command for any X session

Tags: xorg, upstart, scripts

I need to patch the gamma on my monitor that is really out of balance, in short I need to run a command like `xgamma -gamma 1.2` for any X session that I might start on my machine.

My problem is that Ubuntu uses a different startup technology ( upstart ) and I'm not sure where I'm supposed to write this command for my X sessions.

Keep in mind that I need to run this only if an X sessions starts, not everytime at the boot.

Comment: You said precisely on started X session (After login), So it doesn't work with started X server (Before login)?

Comment: @Sneetsher well, I think that will work too, if you can grant that X will execute my command, I guess I'll be fine either ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run the command on session starting (after login), I think this is the simplest way.

Create a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`:

`sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/mygamma.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Gamma
Exec=/usr/bin/xgamma -gamma 1.2
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

Comment: I'm supposed to add the `&` at the end of the command and set `Terminal=true` ? Because `xgamma` is a console app.

Comment: `&` no need as it will be launched in background already. `Terminal=true` no, because you don't want to launch inside a terminal. sure you want it to be quiet, :) not to login with a black welcome window. See [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)